# Computed property gets ran multiple times nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks, nuxt.js, computed-properties

I'm building a relatively big web app with NuxtJS (but this question is about Vue).

I have a homepage which contains many panels, rendered with a v-for.

The list to be rendered is the result of a computed property which relies on many data values:

```js
services() {
      console.log('services')
      const base = [
        {
          header: 'Novità',
          id: 'circolari',
          color: '#1A2B63',
          sync: this.sync.circolare,
          component: () => import('~/components/one_use_component/circolari_list'),
          props: {
            error: this.error.circolare,
            isShowingCircolari: this.isShowingCircolari && this.showCircolari
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'orario',
          color: '#FD4F19',
          sync: null,
          component: () => import('~/components/one_use_component/orario_today'),
          props: {
            today: this.today
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'sondaggi',
          btn: this.$auth.loggedIn && this.$auth.user.scope > 1 ? 'Sondaggi' : false,
          color: '#556080',
          sync: this.sync.sondaggi,
          component: () => import('~/components/one_use_component/sondaggi_available'),
          add: this.$auth.loggedIn && this.$auth.user.scope > 1 ? '/sondaggi/admin/add' : false,
          props: {
            error: this.error.sondaggi
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'treni',
          btn: false,
          color: '#BD392A',
          sync: this.sync.treni,
          modify: '/treni',
          component: () => import('~/components/one_use_component/my_train'),
          props: {
            error: this.error.treni,
            isShowingAndata: this.isShowingAndata
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'giornalino',
          color: '#B0C4D9',
          sync: this.sync.giornalino,
          component: () => import('~/components/one_use_component/last_articles'),
          props: {
            error: this.error.giornalino
          }
        }
      ]
      return this.$auth.loggedIn && this.$auth.user.isValidated
        ? base.filter(s => !(this.$store.state.general.services.unused.indexOf(s.id) !== -1)).sort((a, b) => this.$store.state.general.services.order.indexOf(a.id) - this.$store.state.general.services.order.indexOf(b.id))
        : base.slice(0, 1)
    }
```

During the boot phase, I call methods that update the sync and the error object, that makes the whole computed property to be run multiple times (around 6-7 times) per boot.
How can I make it more efficient? And having the `import` inside it can cause memory leaks or something?